# I need to return the Max count of repeating values in a consecutive data set based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Here is an example of my table:

```
MID RecordDate  Volume
5555    4/1/2017    1
5555    4/2/2017    2
5555    4/3/2017    2
5555    4/4/2017    2
5555    4/5/2017    3
5555    4/6/2017    3
5555    4/7/2017    3
5555    4/8/2017    3
5555    4/9/2017    3
5555    4/10/2017   3
5555    4/11/2017   3
5555    4/12/2017   3
5555    4/13/2017   3
5555    4/14/2017   3
5555    4/15/2017   3
5555    4/16/2017   3
5555    4/17/2017   3
5555    4/18/2017   3
5555    4/19/2017   3
5555    4/20/2017   3
5555    4/21/2017   3
5555    4/22/2017   3
5555    4/23/2017   3
5555    4/24/2017   3
5555    4/25/2017   3
5555    4/26/2017   2
5555    4/27/2017   2
5555    4/28/2017   2
5555    4/29/2017   2
5555    4/30/2017   2
```

I am trying to return the count of consecutive days with the same volume in a defined time period. In my example the data is from 4/1/2017 to 4/30/2017 but in reality would like to adjust this to any date range 30/40/60/90 days..

My expected result would be similar to this:

```
+------+-------------+------------+---------+--------+
| MID  |  Start Date |  End Date  |  Volume |  Count |
+------+-------------+------------+---------+--------+
| 5555 |  4/5/2017   |  4/25/2017 |       3 |     21 |
+------+-------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

I apologize in advance for my poor formatting.  Thanks in advance!

So here was the solution code for that example, can someone else help me make this work for a table that has more than one MID, where I need to pull the largest Count of the interpolation per MID:

```
with cte as 
(
Select top 1
    md1.merrickid
  , StartDate = convert(char(10),min(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , EndDate   = convert(char(10),max(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , md1.EstGasVolMCF
  , cnt       = count(*)
From (
  Select md.MerrickID
  , md.RecordDate
  , md.EstGasVolMCF
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid  order by md.RecordDate) 
          - row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid, md.EstGasVolMCF order by md.RecordDate) 
  From MeterDailyTb as md

  Join CompletionTb as C
    On c.MerrickID = md.MerrickID
  Where md.RecordDate > '3/2/2017' --Parameter for the how far back you want to go
    And c.DrillingTeamID in (24)--Drilling Team Selection Criteria
  ) as md1

--Where md1.merrickid = '105100'
group by md1.merrickid, md1.EstGasVolMCF, grp
order by cnt desc
)
Select *
From cte
Where cte.cnt > 30
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [gaps-and-islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) type question, and can be handled using two [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)s to sort out your islands.

```
select 
    mid
  , StartDate = min(RecordDate)
  , EndDate   = max(RecordDate)
  , Volume
  , cnt       = count(*)
from (
  select *
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by mid  order by RecordDate) 
          - row_number() over (partition by mid, volume order by RecordDate) 
  from t
  ) as s
group by mid, volume, grp
order by mid, StartDate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JBFXNW15938

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=82e7375b5e8d93386f362da547851de8

returns:

```
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| mid  | StartDate  |  EndDate   | Volume | cnt |
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| 5555 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-01 |      1 |   1 |
| 5555 | 2017-04-02 | 2017-04-04 |      2 |   3 |
| 5555 | 2017-04-05 | 2017-04-25 |      3 |  21 |
| 5555 | 2017-04-26 | 2017-04-30 |      2 |   5 |
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
```

---

To return just one row with the highest count, use `top 1` and `order by cnt desc`.

```
select top 1
    mid
  , StartDate = convert(char(10),min(RecordDate),120)
  , EndDate   = convert(char(10),max(RecordDate),120)
  , Volume
  , cnt       = count(*)
from (
  select *
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by mid  order by RecordDate) 
          - row_number() over (partition by mid, volume order by RecordDate) 
  from t
  ) as s
group by mid, volume, grp
order by cnt desc
```

returns:

```
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| mid  | StartDate  |  EndDate   | Volume | cnt |
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| 5555 | 2017-04-05 | 2017-04-25 |      3 |  21 |
+------+------------+------------+--------+-----+
```

---

For updated question:

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
with cte as 
(
select top 1 with ties
    md1.merrickid
  , StartDate = convert(char(10),min(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , EndDate   = convert(char(10),max(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , md1.EstGasVolMCF
  , cnt       = count(*)
From (
  Select md.MerrickID
  , md.RecordDate
  , md.EstGasVolMCF
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid  order by md.RecordDate) 
          - row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid, md.EstGasVolMCF order by md.RecordDate) 
  From MeterDailyTb as md

  Join CompletionTb as C
    On c.MerrickID = md.MerrickID
  Where md.RecordDate > '3/2/2017' --Parameter for the how far back you want to go
    And c.DrillingTeamID in (24)--Drilling Team Selection Criteria
  ) as md1

--Where md1.merrickid = '105100'
group by md1.merrickid, md1.EstGasVolMCF, grp
order by row_number() over (partition by mid order by count(*) desc)
)
Select *
From cte
Where cte.cnt > 30
```

or [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) without [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)

```
with cte as 
(
select 
    md1.merrickid
  , StartDate = convert(char(10),min(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , EndDate   = convert(char(10),max(md1.RecordDate),120)
  , md1.EstGasVolMCF
  , cnt       = count(*)
  , rn        = row_number() over (partition by mid order by count(*) desc)
From (
  Select md.MerrickID
  , md.RecordDate
  , md.EstGasVolMCF
    , grp = row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid  order by md.RecordDate) 
          - row_number() over (partition by md.merrickid, md.EstGasVolMCF order by md.RecordDate) 
  From MeterDailyTb as md

  Join CompletionTb as C
    On c.MerrickID = md.MerrickID
  Where md.RecordDate > '3/2/2017' --Parameter for the how far back you want to go
    And c.DrillingTeamID in (24)--Drilling Team Selection Criteria
  ) as md1

--Where md1.merrickid = '105100'
group by md1.merrickid, md1.EstGasVolMCF, grp
)
Select *
From cte
Where cte.cnt > 30 
  and cte.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi Zim. Is rextester working ok for you today. I haven't be able to open it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No issues for me on rextester. I'll add a db fiddle though.

Comment: Weird. dbfiddle open ok, but rextester doesnt :( .. But isnt just yours, I try create one several times today without sucess.

Comment: Looks like an issue with my office internet, I remote access my home PC and is working ok there. Btw OP probably want `ORDER COUNT(*) DESC`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah, right. Updated for `top 1` `cnt desc`

Comment: Thank you everyone this is very helpful! I am new to Stackoverflow but have learned a lot from my first post.

Comment: @SqlZim could you help me modify this query to work if I have more than one MID? The `order cnt desc` paired with the `Top 1` works if I only have one distinct MID in my table, I need to pull this data for each MID.

Comment: @MatthewMcClendon Updated my answer

Comment: @SqlZim Awesome, Thank you! I was able to get what I needed by removing the `top 1` and `order cnt desc` and filtering my cte to `where cte.cnt > 30` but I think your solution will make this report run much faster!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of below code:

```
    DECLARE @Record TABLE (MID INT,RecordDate DATE, Volume INT)
    INSERT INTO @Record VALUES
    (5555,'4/1/2017',1),
    (5555,'4/2/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/3/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/4/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/5/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/6/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/7/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/8/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/9/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/10/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/11/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/12/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/13/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/14/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/15/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/16/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/17/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/18/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/19/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/20/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/21/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/22/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/23/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/24/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/25/2017',3),
    (5555,'4/26/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/27/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/28/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/29/2017',2),
    (5555,'4/30/2017',2)

    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(Volume),
        COUNT(*)AS [Count],
        MID,
        MIN(RecordDate) AS StartDate,
        MAX(RecordDate) AS EndDate
    FROM 
        @Record
    GROUP BY 
        Volume,MID
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to post this possible solution. The only problem is that this does not take into considering that I only want to count values that are the same and consecutive based on the date range. The Gaps-and-Island solution is exactly the solution I needed.